# Why don't Christians wrap tefillin?

Tags: old-testament, judaism, torah

In Judaism, the most explicit text that commands Jews to wrap tefillin (aka the little black boxes with Bible verses in them that Jews wear on their head and arms) is from Deut. 6:8

> "And you shall bind them for a sign upon your hand, and they shall be for ornaments between your eyes."

More of the background can be [found here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/81814/jewish/Tefillin-and-Its-Significance.htm). Anyway, why do Christians, who see the Old Testament (known in Judaism as the Torah) as holy, not wrap tefillin? Is there are verse similar to the issue of Kashrut (aka "keeping kosher) in the New Testament that negates tefillin?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.   When you have a moment, please take the Christianity Stack tour to learn more about us:  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour   This question may be relevant: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8131/did-jesus-wear-tefillin?rq=1

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/458/23657.   Your question is answered in this related one

Answer (score 1):

Someone better versed in ancient history may be able to offer an authoritative answer, but I can at least offer a biblically-grounded one.

It may have had to do with the entry of Gentile believers into the church.  Acts 10:1-11:18 relates the first significant disagreement resulting from this development (Peter's acceptance of Cornelius and his household), and Acts 15:1-35 relates the debate and council decision as to what the Gentiles "needed" to do, to be accepted into the church as saved brothers.  A significant party within the Jewish brotherhood asserted that the Gentiles had to submit to the entire Law to be saved; Peter, Paul, Barnabas, and James however argued that it was faith in Christ that justified all men in God's sight.  Quoting in part the letter that announced the council's final decision:

> 28 It seemed good to the Holy Spirit and to us not to burden you with
>   anything beyond the following requirements: 29 You are to abstain from
>   food sacrificed to idols, from blood, from the meat of strangled
>   animals and from sexual immorality. You will do well to avoid these
>   things.

In a later writing to the church at Corinth, Paul gave an instruction that only people who had been observant Jews at the time they became Christians, needed to or should continue to observe the entire Law.  Gentile believers needed not do so, and in fact should not do so:

> 17 Nevertheless, each person should live as a believer in whatever
>   situation the Lord has assigned to them, just as God has called them.
>   This is the rule I lay down in all the churches. 18 Was a man already
>   circumcised when he was called? He should not become uncircumcised.
>   Was a man uncircumcised when he was called? He should not be
>   circumcised.   -- 1 Corinthians 7:17-18

Hence, the majority of modern Christians (being non-Jews) would not and indeed should not observe the wearing of tefillin, nor any of the other ceremonial aspects of the Law.